# How do I redirect link for www.example.com/home.php to www.example.com/home?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I got this code from google. I don't know exactly what they want to tell.Can anyone explain me?

```
        RewriteCond %{home}.php -f
        RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{home}.php [L, QSA]
```

Comment: Which part of [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) are you having difficulties with?

Comment: @Oswald Link fail. Link fix. :P

Comment: @Oswald - actually i want to redirect link to www.example.com/home

Comment: Flagged as too broad, because you basically want us to write a redirect tutorial for you. Just read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Simpy use .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

Comment: can you please brief me out?

Comment: To rewrite url you need to use appache possibilities via .htaccess file, and write conditions into it

Answer (score 0):

It's the code of an htaccess file. If you open the url in the directory where this htaccess is stored, you will rewrite the url as specified in the htaccess file.

Here are more informations : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Place this code to your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have placed this code to htaccess file but no output

Comment: Check your apache configuration. Mod_rewrite should be enable to read htaccess file.